# Alarm from AlarmManager is not going off

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

With this code I am setting an alarm in `onCreate` of my `MainActivity` using the `AlarmManager`:

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, startServiceIntent, 0);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);

manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
```

And the code of `MyService` is:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Working", 1).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

But none of the `Toasts` from `MyService` are shown? Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `AlarmManager` really shouldn't be used for any intervals shorter than 30 minutes. Additionally you are using `RTC_WAKEUP`, that combined with the short 1 second interval will only result in the battery being drained like it was leaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is here:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
```

You are setting the calendar to the **28th August 2014 7:47 AM**. So that would be in a month from now... The cause of this problem is here:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 07);
```

Months in a `Calendar` are zero-based:

```
 0 -> January
 1 -> Febuary
 2 -> March
 3 -> April
 4 -> May
 5 -> June
 6 -> July
 7 -> August
 8 -> September
 9 -> October
10 -> November
11 -> December
```

So if you want to set the date to something in July you need to do it like this:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
```

<sub>Also try adding spaces around operators and after commas, makes your code a million times more readable. Oh and some proper indention would also be nice. I already fixed your code formatting this time.</sub>

---

**EDIT:**

The alarm is repeating because you are setting a repeating alarm with `setRepeating()`. If you want the alarm to go off only once then you just need to call `set()` instead, like this:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thank you for editing and answering, if I want to repeat once instead of several times,what i do?(sorry if can not speak good English)

Comment: What do you mean with repeat once? Do you just want the alarm to go off once?

Comment: Yes,this code(Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Working", 1).show();) repeat every 1ms(manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);),i want to run once.